# Renaming Child Nodes in XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am having a problem renaming child nodes in xml files using c#.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ZACAC01>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <ZACGPIAD SEGMENT="1">
      <IDENTIFIER>D000</IDENTIFIER>
      <CUST_DEL_NO/>
      <CUST_DEL_DATE/>
      <TRUCKNO/>
      <DRIVERNAME/>
      <DRIVERID/>
      <RESPONS_OFF/>
      <CONFIRM_DATE>20/01/13</CONFIRM_DATE>
      <SERIAL_NO>2</SERIAL_NO>
      <SERIAL_CHAR/>
      <DEL_INFO1/>
      <QTY>0</QTY>
      <DEL_INFO2/>
      <QTY>0</QTY>
      <DEL_INFO3/>
      <QTY>0</QTY>
      <TRANS_COMPANY>0</TRANS_COMPANY>
    </ZACGPIAD>
  </IDOC>
</ZACAC01>
```

And below is my requirement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ZACAC01>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <ZACGPIADD SEGMENT="1">
      <IDENTIFIER>D000</IDENTIFIER>
      <CUST_DEL_NO/>
      <CUST_DEL_DATE/>
      <TRUCKNO/>
      <DRIVERNAME/>
      <DRIVERID/>
      <RESPONS_OFF/>
      <CONFIRM_DATE>20/01/13</CONFIRM_DATE>
      <SERIAL_NO>2</SERIAL_NO>
      <SERIAL_CHAR/>
      <DEL_INFO1/>
      <QTY1>0</QTY1>
      <DEL_INFO2/>
      <QTY2>0</QTY2>
      <DEL_INFO3/>
      <QTY3>0</QTY3>
      <TRANS_COMPANY>0</TRANS_COMPANY>
    </ZACGPIADD>
  </IDOC>
</ZACAC01>
```

I am able to change the segment tag `<ZACGPIAD>` to this `<ZACGPIADD>` using the following code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.Load(srcfile);
var root = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("IDOC")[0];
var oldElem = root.SelectSingleNode("ZACGPIAD");
var newElem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ZACGPIADD");
root.ReplaceChild(newElem, oldElem);

while (oldElem.ChildNodes.Count != 0)
{
    newElem.AppendChild(oldElem.ChildNodes[0]);
}
while (oldElem.Attributes.Count != 0)
{
    newElem.Attributes.Append(oldElem.Attributes[0]);
}
xmlDoc.Save(desfile);
```

But I can't change the `<QTY>` tag to `<QTY1>`, `<QTY2>`, `<QTY3>`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer right in your code.  You can use `SelectSingleNode` to pull the first `<QTY>` element with this:

```
var qtyNode = root.SelectSingleNode("ZACAC01/IDOC/ZACGPIADD/QTY[1]")
```

then use `ReplaceChild` on it's parent node.  Then do the same for the second and third `<QTY>` nodes, replacing the '1' with '2' and '3' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XDocument` and operate on `XElements` which expose setter for node name (so you can simply set new name instead of doing node replacements):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(srcfile);
var zacgpidNode = doc.Descendants("ZACGPIAD").First();
zacgpidNode.Name = "ZACGPIADD";
// now rename all QTY nodes
var qtyNodes = zacgpidNode.Elements("QTY").ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < qtyNodes.Length; i++)
{
    qtyNodes[i].Name = string.Format("{0}{1}", qtyNodes[i].Name, i+1);
}

doc.Save(desfile);
```

Having `Descendants("ZACGPIAD").First()` might not be suitable if your document structure is different than what you've shown in example. You can use [`XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) method to have more control over what you'll be extracting:

```
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("//IDOC[@BEGIN='1']/ZACGPIAD[@SEGMENT='1']");
```